# Open MS Word Document in MS Word from a C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, forms, button, ms-word, document

I want to be able to open a already made word document in MS word from a C# form by clicking a button on my form but don't know how, Please Help.

Thanks

Answer (score -5, accepted):

What i have done is put the word document in with my .exe file extension of my program in the Release folder and then in my code i have this one line of code when a certain button is pressed:

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("document.docx");

This code basically finds the document and then opens it from the Release folder. Thanks for everyone's help though.

Comment: Thanks for repeating my answer and flagging it as your solution ;)

Answer (score 17):

Last time I worked with excel I opened it using the following code:

```
Process.Start(FileLocation)
```

Guess the same would also work for Word.

Comment: This should work as long as MSWord is registered to open files of type .doc

Comment: And im doing it to open a MS Word 2010 Document if that makes a difference?

Comment: Here's some extra info about this Process class:
Public Class Process
 Inherits System.ComponentModel.Component
 Member of System.Diagnostics

Answer (score 1):

[Creating and Opening Word Documents with C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mgold/wordfromdotnet11082005235506pm/wordfromdotnet.aspx) 
.NET 4.0 makes it [easier](http://omegacoder.com/?p=555) also