# Creating a Word document from code

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, generator

I have made a Windows Form application en now I want to create a Word document. It should be a delivery note, so I have to create columns and a logo etc. and fill this columns with my data.

What kind of library do I need for this?

Comment: Have a look at: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660478/Csharp-Create-and-Manipulate-Word-Documents-Progra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Creating and Opening Word Documents with C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mgold/wordfromdotnet11082005235506pm/wordfromdotnet.aspx) 
.NET 4.0 makes it [easier](http://omegacoder.com/?p=555) also

from [Open MS Word Document in MS Word from a C# Windows Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286221/open-ms-word-document-in-ms-word-from-a-c-sharp-windows-form?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

[Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) is the way to go.

Do not use automation.

Max Mommersteeg suggestion is also good, docX is a decent library.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay clean of Microsoft Interop libraries, I would use some external library you can easily ship with your application.

We use for that NPOI https://npoi.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way is to use .rdlc reports, especially if you are a beginner. These reports can be visualy created (drag and drop) and the reportViewer control can export directly into Word.